# Channel images and Expressionengine MSM

Tags: ee2, multi-site-manager, devdemon, channel-images

I am using the latest version of EE2 and DevDemons channel images.

When i duplicate a site, any channel entry with channel images or channel videos have lost the images & videos.

I assumed when i duplicate a channel and its entries that the images and video links would be copied over also?  Or have i missunderstood?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Third party add-on's data does not get duplicated when you duplicate current channel entries into a new MSM site. EE also doesn't have hooks for this, so it isn't easy for any third party add-on to automate this at all. As far as I know, very few or none even provide a tool for accomplishing this.

You'll need to write a script to port data from one site to another. You'll need to take a look at the database tables Channel Images uses and work out how to duplicate your data associations from your old `field_id`, `entry_id`, `channel_id`, and `site_id`, to your new ones (the new, duplicated channel entries).

I've done this with other add-ons but not Channel Images. You'll have to work it out yourself; you may want to contact the Channel Images author if you run in to trouble understanding their data structures.